# Weighted Least Squares

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I understand the concept of least squares but I'm not able to wrap my head around weighted least squares (the matrix form).
We convert $Ax = b$ to $WAx = Wb$. What exactly happens when we multiply the equation with $W$? Is the column space of A modified based on the changed equations? Also how do I find this matrix $W$, assuming I have the given data (The probability of each observation according to a textbook example "Linear Algebra and it's Applications" by Gilbert Strang, page 174, question 42).
Suppose you guess your professor's age, making errors $e = -2, -1, 5$ with probabilities $1/2, 1/4, 1/4$. If the professor guesses too (or tries to remember), making errors $-1, 0, 1$ with probabilities $1/8, 6/8, 1/8$, what weights $w_1$ and $w_2$ give the reliability of your guess and the professor's guess?

Comment: I believe the matrix $W$ is a diagonal matrix and is essentially a matrix of weights. Perhaps post more context from the textbook so I can say for sure (or include the textbook reference, page number and name of book).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably easiest to understand weighted linear least squares (LLS) by explaining
the motivation behind "ordinary" (i.e., non-weighted) LLS first.

## Ordinary LLS

The setting is as follows: you are given measurements $(x_{1},y_{1}),\ldots,(x_{N},y_{N})$ where $x_{n}\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $y_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$.
You are asked to find an affine function $f$ such that $f(x_{n})\approx y_{n}$ for each $n$.
The hope is that this affine function can give you good estimates of the output parameter $y$ for arbitrary inputs $x$.

One way to find such a function is to pick it such that "mean squared error"
$$
\text{MSE}\equiv\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n}\left(f(x_{n})-y_{n}\right)^{2}
$$
is minimized.
Since $f$ is assumed to be affine, it has the form $f(x)=\beta_{0}+x^{\intercal}\beta_{1}$.
Plugging this into the above,
$$
\text{MSE}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n}\left(\beta_{0}+x_{n}^{\intercal}\beta_{1}-y_{n}\right)^{2}.
$$

Let's take a short detour and rewrite the MSE in terms of matrices and vectors (this well help us in taking derivatives in the next paragraph).
In order to do so, let
$$
X\equiv\begin{pmatrix}1 & x_{1}^{\intercal}\\
1 & x_{2}^{\intercal}\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_{n}^{\intercal}
\end{pmatrix}\text{, }y\equiv\begin{pmatrix}y_{1}\\
y_{2}\\
\vdots\\
y_{n}
\end{pmatrix}\text{,}\text{ and }\beta\equiv\begin{pmatrix}\beta_{0}\\
\beta_{1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then,
$$
\text{MSE}=\frac{1}{N}\Vert X\beta-y\Vert^{2}=\frac{1}{N}\left(X\beta-y\right)^{\intercal}\left(X\beta-y\right).
$$

Recall from calculus that the minimum of the MSE occurs at points where its derivative is zero.
Using [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities), the derivative is
$$
\frac{\partial\text{MSE}}{\partial\beta}=\frac{2}{N}\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\left[X\beta-y\right]\left(X\beta-y\right)=\frac{2}{N}X^{\intercal}\left(X\beta-y\right).
$$
Setting this to zero, we get the equation
$$
X^{\intercal}X\beta=Xy.
$$
Defining $A\equiv X^{\intercal}X$ and $b\equiv Xy$, the above becomes the square linear system $A\beta=b$.
You can solve this with ordinary tools from linear algebra when $A$ is nonsingular. 
You can also solve it when $A$ is singular but doing so requires a notion of [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), which is more advanced material that you can safely ignore for now.

## Weighted LLS

What is weighted LLS?
In weighted LLS, you assign a "belief" to each measurement $(x_{n},y_{n})$.
This allows you to value certain measurements more than others.
The beliefs are positive numbers $w_{1},\ldots,w_{N}$.
The larger $w_{n}$, the more you believe in the measurement $(x_{n},y_{n})$.
The "weighted mean squared error" is
$$
\text{WMSE}\equiv\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n}w_{n}\left(\beta_0 + x_n^\intercal \beta_1-y_{n}\right)^{2}.
$$
Defining the diagonal matrix
$$
W^{\frac{1}{2}}=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{w_{1}}\\
 & \sqrt{w_{2}}\\
 &  & \ddots\\
 &  &  & \sqrt{w_{N}}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
we can rewrite the WMSE in the efficient form
$$
\text{WMSE}=\frac{1}{N}\left(W^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(X\beta-y\right)\right)^{\intercal}\left(W^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(X\beta-y\right)\right).
$$
Taking the derivative,
$$
\frac{\partial\text{WMSE}}{\partial\beta}=\frac{2}{N}\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\left[W^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(X\beta-y\right)\right]W^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(X\beta-y\right)=\frac{2}{N}X^{\intercal}W\left(X\beta-y\right).
$$
Setting this to zero, we get the equation
$$
X^{\intercal}WX\beta=X^{\intercal}Wy.
$$
Defining $A^{(w)}\equiv X^{\intercal}WX$ and $b^{(w)}=X^{\intercal}Wy$, the above becomes the square linear system $A^{(w)}\beta=b^{(w)}$.
As usual, you can tackle this with ordinary linear algebra.

Since the weights are positive and the matrix $W$ is diagonal, the column space of $X^\intercal$ and $X^\intercal W$ are the same.

## Professor's age

We are given two guesses $y_1$ and $y_2$ of the professor's age and asked to produce our own final guess $\beta$ by choosing an appropriate weights $w_1$ and $w_2$.
The MSE in this case is
$$
\text{MSE} \equiv \frac{1}{2} \left[ w_1 \left(\beta - y_1\right)^2 + w_2 \left(\beta - y_2\right)^2 \right].
$$
Defining $X = (1, 1)^\intercal$, $y = (y_1, y_2)^\intercal$ and $W = \operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{w_1}, \sqrt{w_2})$, the arguments above imply that
$$
\beta = (X^\intercal W X)^{-1} X^\intercal W y
$$
minimizes the MSE.
You can check that the above is equivalent to
$$
\beta = \frac{w_1 y_1 + w_2 y_2}{w_1 + w_2}.
$$
Without loss of generality, we can pick $w_2 = 1$ so that
$$
\beta = \frac{w_1 y_1 + y_2}{1 + w_1}.
$$
Next, let $\beta^\star$ be the professors true age.
Note that
$$
\beta - \beta^\star = \frac{w_1 \left(y_1 - \beta^\star\right) + \left(y_2 - \beta^\star\right)}{1 + w_1}.
$$
Let $y_1$ be the student's guess and $y_2$ be the professor's.

As per the question statement, both are [unbiased estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) of the professor's age:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[y_1 - \beta^\star] & = -2 \frac{1}{2} - 1 \frac{1}{4} + 5 \frac{1}{4} = 0\\
\mathbb{E}[y_2 - \beta^\star] & = -1 \frac{1}{8} + 1 \frac{1}{8} = 0
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[\beta - \beta^\star] = 0$, and the expected value cannot help us pick the weights.
Therefore, we look to the variance:
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\beta-\beta^{\star})=\frac{1}{\left(1+w_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(w_{1}^{2}\operatorname{Var}(y_{1}-\beta^{\star})+\operatorname{Var}(y_{2}-\beta^{\star})+2w_{1}\operatorname{Cov}(y_{1}-\beta^{\star},y_{2}-\beta^{\star})\right).
$$
Note that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(y_1 - \beta^\star) & = (-2)^2 \frac{1}{2} + (-1)^2 \frac{1}{4} + 5^2 \frac{1}{4} = \frac{17}{2} \\
\operatorname{Var}(y_2 - \beta^\star) & = (-1)^2 \frac{1}{8} + 1^2 \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}
For brevity, let $c \equiv \operatorname{Cov}(y_{1}-\beta^{\star},y_{2}-\beta^{\star})$.
Plugging these values back into the variance equation,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\beta-\beta^{\star})=\frac{1}{\left(1+w_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(w_{1}^{2}\frac{17}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+2w_{1}c\right).
$$

To pick the "best" weight $w_1$, we try to minimize the variance of $\beta - \beta^\star$.
However, in order to do so, we need the quantity $c$, which was not given to us in the question! As such, we can only make an educated guess.
For example, guessing $c=-1/5$ implies (by ordinary calculus) that $w_1 = 3/58$ is a minimizer of the variance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer, I understand the concept of weighted least squares a lot better now! However, I'm still unclear as to how to assign the weights properly. Perhaps you could tell me the procedure for the problem mentioned in my question or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure, I copied the textbook example. I was thinking that it is possible to find the weights if we knew each error and it's probability. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think I understand the question. I added it to my answer above.

Comment: What does $ \operatorname{Cov}(y_{1}-\beta^{\star},y_{2}-\beta^{\star})$ mean? Could you please clarify?

Comment: $\text{Cov}(A,B)$ is the covariance of $A$ and $B$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance

Comment: Hi! I was just asking if you see page 81 of Boyd and Vandenbergh's book they give an example of weighted LLS. So in that case although not explicitly mentioned are they implying multiple samples i.e. multiple $x_i$?

Comment: @DuttaA: You should ask your question in a new post. This post was asked and answered over a year ago.