# Derive the MLE cost function for linear regression when every observation in the training set has a different, known variance.

Tags: probability, statistics

**Question:**

> Derive the MLE cost function for linear regression when every observation in the training set has a different, known variance.

It has been awhile since I have solved some of these problems by hand. I believe we just need to take the linear regression cost function and show that there exists some minimum, or am I wrong? Any suggestions are appreciated. Really just trying to find resource material to review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_N$ be vectors.
Let $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_N$ be independent random noise with $\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_i^2)$.
Let $y_i = x_i^\intercal \beta + \epsilon_i$ be the observed response.

The MLE is obtained by maximizing the likelihood:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(\beta) = \prod_i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_i}\exp\left\{-\frac{\left(x_i^\intercal \beta-y_i\right)^2}{2\sigma_i^2}\right\}.
\end{equation}
Since the logarithm is strictly increasing, we can equivalently maximize the log-likelihood:
\begin{equation}
\ell(\beta) \equiv \log \mathcal{L}(\beta) = -\frac{N}{2}\log(2\pi) - \sum_i \log \sigma_i - \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2} \left(x_i^\intercal\beta - y_i\right)^2.
\end{equation}
The above is a sum of three terms but only the last term is influenced by the coefficient vector.
In other words, we can reduce the problem one last time: the MLE is the coefficient vector $\beta$ which maximizes
\begin{equation}
\sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma^2_i} (x_i^\intercal \beta - y_i)^2.
\end{equation}
We recognize this as [weighted linear least squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095212/64601) with a weight of $w_i = 1 / \sigma_i^2$.